# Line buffered reading in Perl

Tags: perl, unix

I have a perl script, say "process_output.pl" which is used in the following context:

> long_running_command | "process_output.pl"

The process_output script, needs to be like the unix "tee" command, which dumps output of "long_running_command"  to the terminal as it gets generated, and in addition captures output to a text file, and at the end of "long_running_command", forks another process with the text file as an input.

The behavior I am currently seeing is that, the output of "long_running_command" gets dumped to the terminal, only when it gets completed instead of, dumping output as it gets generated. Do I need to do something special to fix this?

Based on my reading in a few other stackexchange posts, i tried the following in "process_output.pl", without much help:

1. `select(STDOUT); $| =1;`
2. `select(STDIN); $| =1; # Not sure even if this is needed`
3. `use FileHandle; STDOUT->autoflush(1);`
4. `stdbuf -oL -eL long_running_command | "process_output.pl"`

Any pointers on how to proceed further.

Thanks
AB

Answer (score 4):

This is more likely an issue with the *output* of the first process being buffered, rather than the input of your script.  The easiest solution would be to try using the `unbuffer` command (I believe it's part of the `expect` package), something like

```
unbuffer long_running_command | "process_output.pl"
```

The `unbuffer` command will disable the buffering that happens normally when output is directed to a non-interactive place.

Answer (score 1):

This will be the output processing of `long_running_processing`. More than likely it is using `stdio` - which will look to see what the output file descriptor is connected to before it does outputing. If it is a terminal (tty), then it will generally output line based, but in the above case - it will notice it is writing to a pipe and will therefore buffer the output into larger chunks.

You can control the buffering in your own process by using, as you showed

```
select(STDOUT); $| =1;
```

This means that things that your process prints to STDIO, are not buffered - it makes no sense doing this for input, as you control how much buffering is done - if you use `sysread()` then you are reading unbuffered, if you use a construct like `<$fh>` then perl will await until it has a "whole line" (it actually reads up to the next input line separator (as defined in variable `$/` which is newline by default)) before it returns data to you.

`unbuffer` can be used to "disable" the output buffering, what it actually does is make the outputing process think that it is talking to a `tty` (by using a pseudo tty) so the output process does not buffer.