# Perl STDIN without buffering or line buffering

Tags: perl, io, stdin, buffering

I have a Perl script that received input piped from another program. It's buffering with an 8k (Ubuntu default) input buffer, which is causing problems. I'd like to use line buffering or disable buffering completely. It doesn't look like there's a good way to do this. Any suggestions?

```
use IO::Handle;
use IO::Poll qw[ POLLIN POLLHUP POLLERR ];
use Text::CSV;

my $stdin = new IO::Handle;
$stdin->fdopen(fileno(STDIN), 'r');
$stdin->setbuf(undef);

my $poll = IO::Poll->new() or die "cannot create IO::Poll object";
$poll->mask($stdin => POLLIN);

STDIN->blocking(0);

my $halt = 0;
for(;;) {
    $poll->poll($config{poll_timout}); 

    for my $handle ($poll->handles(POLLIN | POLLHUP | POLLERR)) {
        next unless($handle eq $stdin);

        if(eof) {
            $halt = 1;
            last;
        }

        my @row = $csv->getline($stdin);
        # Do more stuff here
    }

    last if($halt);
}
```

Polling STDIN kind of throws a wrench into things since IO::Poll uses buffering and direct calls like sysread do not (and they can't mix). I don't want to infinitely call sysread without no blocking. I require the use of `select` or `poll` since I don't want to hammer the CPU.

**PLEASE NOTE: I'm talking about STDIN, NOT STDOUT. $|++ is not the solution.**

**[EDIT]**
Updating my question to clarify based on the comments and other answers.

The program that is writing to STDOUT (on the other side of the pipe) is line buffered and flushed after every write. Every write contains a newline, so in effect, buffering is not an issue for STDOUT of the first program.

To verify this is true, I wrote a small C program that reads piped input from the same program with STDIN buffering disabled (setvbuf with _IONBF). The input appears in STDIN of the test program immediately. Sadly, it does not appear to be an issue with the output from the first program.
**[/EDIT]**

Thanks for any insight!

PS. I have done a fair amount of Googling. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351500/perl-disable-buffering-input) is the closest I've found to an answer, but it certainly doesn't satisfy all my needs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21956697/223226

Comment: Your example code wouldn't "hammer the CPU" if you changed it to read STDIN line-by-line in the usual way. CPU usage only becomes a concern when you're doing non-blocking reads so that the program can do something else while it's waiting for the data. Maybe your real program is doing something more sophisticated.

Comment: Re "I don't want to infinitely call sysread without no blocking", Why not call `sysread` with blocking? `sysread` will always return as soon as data arrives. (Won't solve your problem, but it makes your program a whole lot simpler.)

Comment: I can't use blocking because other tasks are handled that aren't included in the pasted code (child reaping, etc). That leaves me with the option to infinitely loop over the sysread (with no blocking) that (if I recall correctly) will peg the CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say there are two short lines in the pipe's buffer.

IO::Poll notifies you there's data to read, which you proceed to read (indirectly) using `readline`.

Reading one character at a time from a file handle is very inefficient. As such, `readline` (aka `<>`) reads a block of data from the file handle at a time. The two lines ends up in a buffer and the first of the two lines is returned.

Then you wait for IO::Poll to notify you that there is more data. It doesn't know about Perl's buffer; it just knows the pipe is empty. As such, it blocks.

[This post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=815969) demonstrates the problem. It uses IO::Select, but the principle (and solution) is the same.

Comment: Great! I was able to adapt it and resolved the issue!

Answer (score 3):

You're actually talking about the *other program's STDOUT*. The solution is `$|=1;` (or equivalent) in the other program.

If you can't, you might be able to convince the other program use line-buffering instead of block buffering by connecting its STDOUT to a pseudo-tty instead of a pipe (like Expect.pm does, for example).

The unix program `expect` has a tool called `unbuffer` which does that exactly that. (It's part of the `expect-dev` package on Ubuntu.) Just prefix the command name with `unbuffer`.

Comment: Yeah, you have no control over how the other program handles buffering. You'll have to fix this at the source.

Comment: @tadman, A few programs give you a command line option to disable buffering, but that's very rare.

Comment: Thankfully, the program performing the output is line buffered. It makes an explicit flush after each line output. Each line that is written has a newline character in it. I believe it's STDIN that's buffered.

Comment: Also, I'm confident that STDOUT is flushed from the primary program because I wrote a test program in C, disabled line buffering completely on STDIN and received the full data instantly.

Comment: It could be that IO::Poll requires that you use `sysread` for the same [reason](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=815969) IO::Select does.

Comment: Good find! IO::Select provides the functionality I need from IO::Poll, so I'll use that with the sysread option. It's more complicated, but hopefully it will do the job.

Comment: Wasn't really a "find" since I wrote the linked post :) (You can probably find other useful IO::Select snippets by me on PerlMonks.) Also, you don't need to stop using IO::Poll; the solution for IO::Select will work for IO:Poll too. Anyway, posted a new answer. Leaving this one cause it could still be useful to some.